# Properties of determinants.

Tags: determinant

Is this property of a determinant true?

$$|A^3| = |A|^3.$$

I haven't studied about this but while working out on a sum, wondered if this could be true, I'll check out on other sums too if this works.

Comment: Yes, that's true for any power..

Comment: you could simply have checked [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: use $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.